# PHPMailer sending multiple emails to every receipents in database

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using this code to send email to everyone in the database in a loop. Problem occurred when I find out that user 1 in database also getting all emails sent to other users in the database. User 2 gets all email sent to other users after him and so on. I want to send a single email to everyone customized with their name and emails. Did check and applied couple of solutions from this forum but they are not working.

```
#SEND EMAILS

        require '../includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        require '../includes/PHPMailer/config.php';

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Host = $smtp_server_w;
        $mail->Username = $username_w;
        $mail->Password = $password_w;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        $mail->Port = 465;

        $mail->setFrom("test@test.com", "Test Name");

        $sql_mail = "SELECT * FROM users";

        $run_mail = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_mail);
        while ($row_mail = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_mail)) {

        $name = $row_mail["user_name"];
        $email = $row_mail["user_email"];
        $mail->ClearAddresses();

        $mail->addAddress('test@test.com', 'Test Name'); 
        $mail->addBCC($email, $name);

        $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

        $bodyContent = "<p>Multiple Messages</p>";

        $mail->Subject = $row_mail['user_name'].", New job is available " ;
        $mail->Body    = $bodyContent;
        $mail->AltBody = $bodyContent;


        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Message could not be sent.";
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Mailer Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo.'</strong></div>';
        } else {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Message has been sent</strong></div>';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: PHPMailer::clearAddresses only clears the 'to' addresses.

Comment: You want PHPMailer::clearBCCs if you want to clear the BCCs.

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a try... I get back to you in a second.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Progrock. It worked for bcc but still it's sending all emails to addAddress...

Comment: Look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer.

Comment: Your code as you listed to begin with, loops through your users, adds a to address of test@test.com on each loop and adds a bcc address and sends within the loop.  So as I see it you could have three to addresses and three bcc addresses by the third loop and so on.  The first user will have the contents of the third users mail etc.  You could clear the addresses each time.  Or just add multiple BCCs and do one send.  (Or even clone the original mailing object, assign, send and discard.)

Comment: Yeah, I did that and that is why it worked with the bcc. but same thing should happen for address because If in first loop, it sends email to Address, then in next loop, as I have already cleared the Address, it should just skip it and goes to the next bcc email address. Isn't it? Thanks Synchro...Checking it.